# How to use ASP.NET identity local users in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have two Azure-hosted web applications, one built with ASP.NET MVC (.NET Framework) and the other built on ASP.NET Core 3.1.

At present the .NET Framework app users local user accounts for authentication, while the .NET Core app uses Azure AD accounts.

Is it possible to use the same local user accounts created by the .NET Framework app to authenticate users in the .NET Core app? If it is possible, what changes do I need to make to the .NET Core application?

Comment: Please can you provide sample code for how the authentication is configured? To clarify, by local accounts, do you mean those stored in a SQL Database?

Comment: Yes, by local accounts I mean those stored in the app's database.

Comment: Maybe!!!  Are you making a HTTP (not secure) connection or HTTPS (secure).  You should be able to make the same connection on both if not secure.  If you are using a secure connection, it also should work provided you are not using encryption modes that are obsolete.

Comment: sync local user accounts to azure ad